# Where does Digikam store video meta data?

Tags: exif, digikam

I have configured Digikam to store metadata (such as tags and ratings) in the files themselves (under SETTINGS > CONFIGURE DIGIKAM > METADATA). This seems to have worked well for my photos. I changed computers recently and I could simply transfer my photos and Digikam re-indexed all tags and ratings by simply reading the EXIF information from the files. However, my video tags and ratings have NOT been transferred properly. All of the videos seem to lack meta data.

Where is this stored? And is there a way to just transfer the files from my old computer to my new computer without having to restore Digikam databases?

Comment: what did the digikam support tell you?

Comment: What Digikam support do you refer to exactly?

Comment: explore the digikam website ... https://www.digikam.org/ ... that should have been done before posting here

Comment: Sorry, could you perhaps point me to a specific section? I have been unable to find this on Digikam. Maybe I don't use the right search words but I just can't find where they explain this.

Comment: search for the word `support` on that webpage

Comment: Okay, I have found the Digikam mailing list. I will ask the question there instead. Apologies if this was the wrong place to ask this question.

Comment: it is not necessarily the wrong place to ask ... it just should be asked after some research is done